# Where can I find more information about Litecoin ASIC miners?

Tags: litecoin, mining-hardware, asic

I know Bitcoin can use ASICs but from what I can see some ASIC based hardware can work with Litecoin as well. However google search wise there isn't much to go off of, just that it is possible.

Any guides or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Just search for "scrypt asic miner" and you should find some.
[https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=VFzxWJPGCuHs8wek4pPIBg#q=scrypt+asic+miner](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=VFzxWJPGCuHs8wek4pPIBg#q=scrypt%20asic%20miner)

Comment: 404 error.  page cannot be found

Comment: i guess they sold out, the updated link is to search results